# How to insert multiple rows of data to a database table inside a for loop

Tags: php

How do I insert multiple rows of data to a database table inside a for loop.

Example: I need to run the following for loop for 7 times to insert names of DAYS to the database.

```
for ($t = 0 ; $t < 7; $t++){
    $defaultValues = "INSERT INTO workingDays (businessID, day, workingHours) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $pdo->prepare($defaultValues)->execute([$businessID, $dayNames, $hours]);
}
```

In the end, the `workingDays` table should be like this:

```
BusinessID: 1, Day: Monday, workingHours: 8
BusinessID: 1, Day: Tuesday, workingHours: 8
BusinessID: 1, Day: Wednesday, workingHours: 8
BusinessID: 1, Day: Thursday, workingHours: 8
BusinessID: 1, Day: Friday, workingHours: 8
BusinessID: 1, Day: Saturday, workingHours: 8
BusinessID: 1, Day: Sunday, workingHours: 8
```

Comment: to to to to looooooop. And punctuation isn't optional.

Comment: my bad. edited.

Comment: Lookup _PHP + Date + DayOfTheWeek_. Hint _l (lowercase ‘L’)_

Comment: You don't need to prepare the statement every time through the loop. Prepare it once and execute it repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over an array of day names.

```
$defaultValues = "INSERT INTO workingDays (businessID, day, workingHours) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($defaultValues);
$daynames = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', ..., 'Sunday'];
foreach ($daynames as $day) {
    $stmt->execute([$businessID, $day, $hours]);
}
```